# How to put a text into the background on a text input?

Tags: html, css, image, input, background

I have an input where users will put a number of their car. When is there the action new, then is in the input a placeholder text saying "Car number".

But when users edit the car information, then there's no placeholder but the number that a user put into the form. I would like to remind them that this input is for setting a "Car number", like on the image below:
[image]

But how to put a text on the background of an input? I know how to put on the background an image, but is there any way to put there a text label?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just fake it with Z-stacking and a transparent background on the `input`:

```
<div class="car">
    <label for="carnr">Car Number</label>
    <input id="carnr" name="carnr" type="number">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.car {
    position:relative;
}
.car input {
    background:transparent;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:3px;
    width:400px;
    padding:4px 4px;
}
.car label {
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:3px;
    width:380px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

[Sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/awtUu/).

Answer (score 0):

You could pull the label into the text box by using negative margins, but this can become tedious as the values of the padding and margin will change based on the length of the string.

http://jsfiddle.net/T9kpc/

html:

```
<input class="input" type="text">
<label class="placeholder">car number</label>
```

css:

```
.placeholder {
    color:#aaa;
    margin-left:-100px; /*the important part*/
    border-left:2px dotted #eee;
    padding-left:10px
}
.input {
    height:30px;
    border-radius:4px;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    padding:5px 100px 5px 10px; /*the important part*/
    font-size:16px;
    outline:none;
}
```

Most of the above is stylistic but the important parts are the negative margin of the label and the padding of the input. if you don't put a big enough padding-right on the input then the text will overlap with the label.

I would also advise against using red for the label color because typically with forms, red indicates field error and could confuse the user. There are a lot of resources that discuss best practices for forms you can look into, here are a couple I found with a quick search.

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9220/on-forms-is-inline-placeholder-text-better-than-a-label-outside-each-field

http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/08/extensive-guide-web-form-usability/

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML placeholder.

`<input type="text" placeholder="Car number"/>`

This will display the text inside the textbox.([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Goudgeld1/jPwFD/))

Answer (score -1):

use value

```
    <input name="test" value="i am pre entered text"></input>
```

hope this helps :)